# SSRS Send Email failing

Tags: email, reporting-services, smtp

I am trying  to send email via SSRS subscription service.I get a success message but do not receive any email. I checked the log file and got the below error message
"ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for myemail".
Kindly help.

Comment: Sounds like a network error.   I'd show it to your network admin.

Comment: Have you set up your SSRS server to connect to your mail server? Unfortunately it is not able to just send out email without some fairly intense configuration: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx)

Comment: Thanks all. I was able to connect.I guess the user didn't have the rights to send mails via the smtp. Changing the user i think solved the problem.